# How to estimate sums over arithmetic progressions?

Tags: order-theory, arithmetic-functions, estimation-theory

1. For $x>1$
   $$
   N(x)=\sum_{0<n<x \\n \equiv 1 \pmod 4\\ n\text{ squarefree}} 1
   $$
   How to estimate $N(x)$'s order? (Like $N(x) \sim Ax$)
2. Furthermore, for $n=p_1p_2\cdots p_v$, define $\alpha (n)=v$  ,then for $x>1$
   $$
   M(x)=\sum_{0<n<x \\n \equiv 1 \pmod 6\\ n\text{ squarefree}} 2^{\alpha (n)}
   $$
   How to estimate $M(x)$'s order?

In fact, I want to learn some methods to estimate these sums. Are there some books, articles or lessons about it?

Comment: For 1, we have a recurrence relation $$\sum_{\substack{a\leq\sqrt{x}\\ a=\text{odd}}}N(\lfloor{\frac{x}{a^2}}\rfloor)≈\frac{x}{4}$$ Hence, as a rough estimation if $N \sim Ax$, $A$ should be $\frac{2}{\pi^2}$.

Comment: Two 'black box' methods include the Selberg-Delange method and Wirsing's theorems. See e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/408819/asymptotic-lower-bound-for-the-number-of-square-free-with-at-least-two-prime-fac/408918). If you don't have a congruence condition, these problems are just summation of multiplicative functions. To deal with the congruence condition you have to show cancellation in your sums twisted by a Dirichlet character.